# Activating android application

Tags: android

I am installing app using **update.zip**.
When device is loading up, app does not receive *BOOT_COMPLETED* intent even after rebooting. It starts receiving intent only after I first launch the app. According to [this post](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/activating-applications/)

application is not yet active.
The question is : 
Where could be the file to change with list of applications subscripted to *BOOT_COMPLETED* intent ?
Application should receive intent right after updating with **update.zip**

Answer (score 0):

Found that file in */data/system/users/0*  - **package-restrictions.xml**

 Just removed the 3rd line here

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
    <package-restrictions>
    <pkg name="my.application.package" stopped="true" nl="true" />
```